# Search a number in LinQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
public JsonResult SearchProduct(int page, int pageSize, string key)
        {
            using (context = new ACETeaEntities())
            {
                var lstCatalog = context.Drinks.Select(x => new { x.Id_drinks, x.Vie_name, x.Eng_name, x.Id_category, x.Cool, x.Numberoforder, x.Price }).Where(x => x.Id_drinks.Contains(key) || x.Vie_name.Contains(key) || x.Eng_name.Contains(key) || x.Id_category.Contains(key) || x.Numberoforder.ToString() == key || (x.Cool == true ? "Có Lạnh" : "").Contains(key)).ToList();
                var data = lstCatalog.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
                int totalRow = lstCatalog.Count();
                return Json(new
                {
                    data = data,
                    total = totalRow,
                    status = true
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

I have a search warrant as above. But I can not find the number for the keyword. 
It will select all numbers containing the number 'key'. And I also can not convert into string to use Contains(key).

Error: 
System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Numberoforder : Number of orders (int);

Cool : (bool) 
Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Include a variable - `int num = Convert.ToInt32(key)` and use `x.Numberoforder == num` in the query

Comment: If so. The result will return the exact same number. Is there a way to find the approximate number?

Comment: hat do you mean 'approximate' number'?

Comment: The closest number to the key

Comment: Sorry, your not making sense.

Comment: so sorry. I do not know how to describe it. Example:
Data {111,222,333}; Key search = "1"; Desired result is '111'

Comment: But what is the logic for that? What if  values`11` and `10` and `1115` exist - which one would it select?

Comment: It will select all numbers containing the number 1

Comment: Then you should explain that in your question (it not an _approximate number_). Use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Numberoforder).Contains(key)`

Comment: It has worked. Thank you very much!